# Subsetting numpy arrays

Tags: numpy

I want to subset a `d = (d1,...,dn)`-shaped numpy array `A` to get only the `r = (r1,...,rn)` first principal minor, i.e all values `A[i1,...,in]` such that `ij < rj`. The resulting array has shape `r`, of course.

How can i do that ? I tried `A[:r]` but of course it did not work :). The right way would be `A[:r1,...,:rn]`, but `len(A.shape)` is unknown, so i cant write all subsetting one by one.

Do you have an idea on how i could get this submatrix ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
A[tuple([slice(None, i) for i in r])]
```

Comment: Perfec, thanks. Did not know about the slice() function !

Comment: The inner pair of square brackets are unnecessary, but otherwise looks good.